# ES6 Class: call method in method (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, class, events, xmlhttprequest

I have the following method in my class:

```
triggerSuccess() {
        return function(){
            var DONE = 4;
            var HTTP_OK = 200;
            if (this.readyState === DONE) {

                // This throws an error:
                this.removeEventListener('error', this.triggerError());
                //

                if (this.status === HTTP_OK) {
                    logger.debug('File upload complete');
                } else {
                    var error;
                    if(this.status === 0){
                        error = new Error('ConferenceFileShareUpload: CORS request failed')
                    } else {
                        error = new Error('this.statusText');
                    }
                    error.status = this.status;
                    logger.error('File upload failed: %s', error.message, event);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

This is called in another method:

```
upload(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return this.request()

                ...

                }).send().then((result)=>{
                    var uploadUrl = result.message.body.uploadUrl;
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.addEventListener('load', this.triggerSuccess());

                    ...

                    resolve();
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
```

I get now in my triggerSuccess() the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.triggerError is not a function

But I have it in my class:

```
triggerError(err) {
    this.events.emit(FileShareEvent.error, err);
}

onError(listener) {
    this.emitter.on(FileShareEvent.error, listener);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `triggerError` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, updated my question!

Comment: Did you create a new instance before you tried to call the method?

Comment: New instance inside the triggerSuccess? Nope, will try that.